# Build:Cannot find module OurFirstAppWithFVisualStudio.module.scss

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I am using NodeJS tools for visual studio for building a SPF App like shown here:

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/wiki/Working-with-visual-studio

However after doing all steps, I have this error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     Build:Cannot find module
>   './OurFirstAppWithFVisualStudio.module.scss'. NodejsApp1  E:\GoogleDrive\Labs\SPF\OurFirstSPFAppWithVisualStudio\src\webparts\ourFirstAppWithFVisualStudio\OurFirstAppWithFVisualStudioWebPart.ts 8

When I checked the solution, I noticed the .scss file was excluded from the solution, so my first action was to include it in the project.

However that didnt have any effect.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is perhaps that typescript cannot find the typings for for your module `OurFirstAppWithFVisualStudio.module.css` which it is being unable to resolve your module. Try `require`ing the styles. If typescript is unable to resolve the `require` function add the following in a `.d.ts` file

```
declare interface IRequire {
<T>(path: string): T;
(paths: string[], callback: (...modules: any[]) => void): void;
ensure: (paths: string[], callback: (require: <T>(path: string) => T) => void) => void;
}

declare var require: IRequire;
```

In your project. You don't need to do `import styles from './...scss'`. Simply importing or requiring the file should do the trick. Although make sure you have configured the style loaders in your `webpack.config.js` or any other bundler if you're not using webpack. You can follow [this](https://shellmonger.com/2016/01/19/adding-sass-support-to-webpack/) article to configure the loaders in webpack. If neither of these work for perhaps you can create declaration files for your css modules using [typed-css-modules](https://github.com/Quramy/typed-css-modules)